# Quelle est la différence entre « nounounerie » et « niaiserie » en français du Québec ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, québec, régionalismes, dictionnaires

Quelle est le différence ou nuance de sens ou d'emploi entre la [*nounounerie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nounounerie) et la [*niaiserie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/niaiserie), essentiellement la *bêtise*, en français du Québec ; y a-t-il une raison particulière qui explique l'[entrée](https://www.lapresse.ca/arts/litterature/2021-05-05/guy-delisle-fait-son-entree-dans-le-petit-larousse-illustre.php) de la première au *Petit Larousse illustré* de l'année (2022) ?

Answer (score 2):

Les termes québécois sélectionnés pour les dictionnaires le sont autant pour leur aspect pittoresque que pour leur utilité.

Il n'y a aucune différence évidente (ou, probablement, réelle) de sens entre *nounounerie* et *niaiserie* (de la même manière qu'il n'y en a pas beaucoup dans l'usage entre une "idiotie" et une "stupidité"). En fait, je n'avais jamais entendu *nounounerie* de ma vie. C'est un terme beaucoup plus rare que *niaiserie*, d'ailleurs, n'est ce pas éminemment révélateur que dans la citation, *nounounerie* a été mis entre guillemet, alors que ce ne serait jamais le cas de *niaiserie*?

Answer (score 1):

Je suis généralement d'accord avec les constats faits dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/45291). Par ailleurs *nounounerie* dérive directement du nom [*nounoune*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nounoune#fr) et il y a à mon avis des nuances d'emploi, comme entre [*nono*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nono) et [*niaiseux*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/niaiseux) d'ailleurs. Même si Wiktionnaire marque le premier comme péjoratif et non le deuxième, il montre par ailleurs que ce dernier peut être employé pour insulter, alors qu'on voit mal *nono/nounoune* employé à cette fin (encore moins précédé d'un juron) et on peut même l'employer de manière hypocoristique il me semble. C'est pour cette raison que je comprends *nounounerie* comme plus directement relié à *nono/nounoune* et un peu comme un synonyme par euphémisme ou un emploi moins péjoratif/négatif que *niaiserie/(niais)/niaiseux*. Ce n'est que mon intuition et je ne sais pas ce que d'autres locuteurs en pensent et je n'ai pas comparé des contextes d'emplois pour vérifier.

Pour ce qui est de la sélection des mots à ajouter au dictionnaire, ça semble très variable et parfois anecdotique :

> [Le choix des mot est] issu de discussions avec des conseillers
> locaux, confirme M. Melançon. « Ce sont des choses qui ne sont jamais
> dites très clairement », dit-il. On y trouve aussi, forcément, une
> part de subjectivité. (Le devoir, [*Une «nounounerie» de plus au
> Larousse*](https://www.ledevoir.com/culture/600103/langue-francaise-une-nounounerie-de-plus-au-larousse))

Le blogue de [*L'Oreille tendue*](http://oreilletendue.com/2021/05/05/six-remarques-sur-le-petit-larousse-illustre-2022/) critique le choix d'inclure le mot en priorité. Le mot est certainement rare quand on le compare à *niaiserie* comme on l'a dit ailleurs, mais il est attesté à l'écrit depuis un bon moment déjà, on le trouve à [plus](https://books.google.com/books?id=72AuAAAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3AI2zM3THQQcgC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=nounounerie) d'une reprise dans au moins une oeuvre québécoise comme [*Le Cassé*](https://electrodes-h-sinclair-502.com/le-casse-nouvelles-de-jacques-renaud/) de [Jacques Renaud](https://www.lapresse.ca/arts/livres/201307/29/01-4675063-le-casse-de-jacques-renaud-dune-violence-inouie.php) par exemple. On verra si son inscription au PLI le rendra plus courant...

Comment: Avec *nounounerie* il y a la notion de *béatitude* devant le jeune enfant qui subjectivement incite à ***bétifier*** [Larousse] « Dire des niaiseries, parler, agir d'une manière *puérile*. » … le *niais* ne peut dire des *niaiseries* qu'après *l'âge social de raison*, ce qui permet alors toutes les perversions/modulations d'intention.